Movie I saw in 1974 or 1975 with corrupt marshal after a man and woman
Movie I saw in 1974 or 1975 on TV. It could have been a TV movie, but I doubt it. It was about a nasty and corrupt marshal after a man and woman because they are robbing the rich and giving to the poor. He kills one of their friends by dropping him into a snakepit filled with venomous snakes. The movie ends with cops shooting woman as she is getting out of the car and the man manages to run close enough to sheriff to shoot and kill him despite being shot numerous times.

I think you're after Thomasine & Bushrod from 1974.

A rare blaxploitation classic starring Vonette McGee & Max Julien, Thomasine & Bushrod was intended as a counterpart to Bonnie and Clyde. This pair of thieves, who operate in the American south between 1911 and 1915, pattern themselves after Robin Hood and hold the White Establishment as (a 'modern-day') Sheriff of Nottingham. Here's the clincher - Thomasine and Bushrod steal from rich, white capitalists, then give to Mexicans, Native Americans and poor whites.

They're hunted by a Marshal called Bogardie throughout the film, and he throws their friend Jomo into a snake pit. They confront him eventually and it doesn't end well. Here's a scene:




This could be the movie I'm asking about. I will try to either find out more info about the movie or watch it somewhere to confirm. Thanks.

No problem. The Marshal appears in the clip I've attached, if that helps. And I think the couple dies in the end.

I haven't been able to verify that this is the movie yet, but since the bounty is over and this is the only answer that could be right. I'm awarding the bounty to Walt. If this is the right movie I can see why I had such a hard time finding it. It supposedly was shown on TV a couple times in the mid 70s, then it pretty much disappeared until a couple years ago. It was never released on VHS, but finally released on DVD and shown on cable TV a couple years ago.

Thanks. It's indeed obscure... Good luck (and good question, BTW).

I just finished watching Thomasine and Bushrod. It is the movie the I saw 40 years ago. Thank you very much Walt.

Is it possibly Macon County Line? http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0071788/
Right time period, right plot ... Don't know about the snakes though. I saw this when I was a kid many years ago.

Aren't they brothers there, though (instead of a man and a woman)?

They are two brothers that are being pursued by the marshal yes, but they hook up with a woman drifter during the movie. I thought "two guys and a woman" was close enough to "a man and wife" that OP may have misremembered this detail. But, as I said, I don't recall or have independent knowledge of any snake pit in Macon County Line, and that is a much more memorable detail. :-)

Oh - OP saw the movie on TV in the 1970's and it may have been a made for TV movie? I think this makes it much less likely to be Macon County Line then, which was chock full of nudity, violence and swearing.

I don't think this is the movie I'm looking for, but it is one I've always wanted to see, but still haven't.
